# Контуженый или контуженный?

Tags: орфография

**Нет порядка с этим словом в нашей орфографии.** Так,  в Нацкорпусе на 67 примеров с двумя НН приходится 33 примера с одной Н, причем выбор НН или Н не зависит от грамматической конструкции (пишут как кому нравится).

В словаре указаны два варианта (причастие и прилагательное), но ведь глагол "контузить" совершенного вида, по правилу нужно писать две буквы НН.

**КОНТУЗИТЬ** ; **контуженный**; -жен,  **св**. кого. Нанести контузию. Командир контужен в голову. □безл. Его контузило взрывной волной.

**КОНТУЖЕНЫЙ,** -ая, -ое. Получивший контузию. К. боец. Вернуться с войны контуженым. / Разг. Обнаруживающий в поведении психические отклонения; со странностями. Ты что, контуженый?

Примеры

Обидно было за сына, и почувствовала она зависть к Александрине: хотя и **контуженный**, но вот вернулся. [Василь Быков). Лошадь Даву была убита, сам маршал, **контуженный** и оглушенный, упал и был придавлен убитой под ним лошадью. [Е. В. Тарле).

Она молча поднялась наверх и, судя по звукам ― будто **контуженый** танкист над его головой все время менял направление движения танка, ― минут пять потерянно бродила по комнатам (Дина Рубина). Больной, **контуженый** подполковник присвоил чьи-то стихи, был разоблачен и изгнан безжалостно (Константин Ваншенкин).

Comment: Мне почему-то вспоминается правило про причастия и прилагательные, которые пишутся по-разному...

Comment: Пары причастие-прилагательное обычно образуют глаголы несовершенного вида (крашеный - крашенный в прошлом году). Такую пару образует двувидовой глагол "ранить", но "контузить" - глагол совершенного вида.

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C#.D0.A0.D0.BE.D0.B4.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0

Comment: Забыл добавить - смотрите "родственные слова" в этой статье.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С двувидовым глаголом "контузить"действует правило о причастий не на - -ованный (-ёванный, -еванный) глаголов несовершенного вида и соотносительных с ними прилагательных; причастия пишутся с двумя нн( при наличие пояснительных слов), прилагательные - с одним н. По этому правилу пишутся и следующие двувидовые глаголы: контузить, крестить и ранить.

> контуженный в голову боец, тяжело раненный солдат, раненный в ногу солдат, только что крещённый младенец, но: контуженый командир, раненый солдат, крещёный ребёнок.

См.: Академический справочник.

Comment: Что-то формулировка непонятная. И еще, кто это придумал, что глагол контузить - двувидовой? Кто-нибудь может привести пример фразы с НСВ? Я представить ее себе не могу,  смысл действия не позволяет.

Comment: Человека контузит одномоментно - бац, и готово; сильно может контузить, а вот долго - никак.

Comment: 1) Да, в Викисловаре  тоже указано, что глагол совершенного вида, например: "Водяных ужей Надины куры охаживают смело, будто червяков: зажав в клюве, молотят, хлещут их об землю, пока тех не контузит (что сделает)". Вот глагол "ранить" точно двувидовой: Ты ранишь сердце мне (что делаешь/что сделаешь). 2) Но семантически эти глаголы похожи, и в принципе можно представить отглагольные прилагательные со значением качества "раненый и контуженый", которые обозначают постоянный признак.

Comment: 3) Не стоит забывать еще об одном правиле, а именно: при обособлении мы используем форму причастия "раненный" даже при отсутствии зависимых слов, например:Орел, хоть и раненный, вполне мог перевернуть неустойчивую лодку. А я в кремлевской комнате залег, раненный. ТАК КАК ПРАВИЛЬНО ПИСАТЬ И ОБЪЯСНЯТЬ?

Comment: Академический справочник единственное издание  (которое мне удалось найти), где глагол "контузить'' представлен как двувидовой. В словарях этот глагол совершенного вида.

Comment: Но что мешает этот глагол писать по аналогии с глаголом ''ранить''?Вспомните, что говорится у Розенталя:                               *** ''Разграничение страдательных причастий и образованных от них прилагательных (тем самым выбор написания нн или н) иногда производится не по формальному признаку, а по смысловому значению. Например- в предложении Будучи раненным, солдат оставался в строю в слове раненным пишется нн, несмотря на отсутствие приставки и пояснительных слов: ***

Comment: ***оно сохраняет глагольное значение, указывает не на постоянный признак-качество, а на временное состояние, т. е. является причастием. Отглагольное прилагательное не обозначает действия и отвечает на вопрос: «какой?» («какая?», «какое?», «какие?»).''***

Comment: Серж, а  вы сами, без словарей,  как бы определили вид глагола? Глаголы "ранить и контузить" очень похожи, и мне кажется, им обоим  и без зависимых слов можно бы иметь две формы написания, но  "раненный" только в обособленных конструкциях, а "контуженый" только в переносном значении.

Comment: Вера, глагол ''контузить'' я еще могу определить как двувидовой. напр.: Его контузили несколько раз ( хотя пример и спорный). А вот можно ли сказать: его раняло(?) несколько раз?

Comment: В приведенных вами примерах нет ошибки. Я бы ни грамм не сомневаясь написал бы так, как в примерах.

Comment: Вера, а вот по поводу переносного значения я не очень понимаю. В  смысле ненормальный?

Comment: Да, когда можно заменить "прилагательным. И еще при однородных отношениях можно писать одну букву Н: больной, контуженый. Таким образом, здесь требуется смысловое решение и грамматический анализ.

Comment: Да, Вера, вот именно смысловое решение. Ведь говорится в справочнике, иногда разграничение производится по смысловому значению.

Answer (score 2):

По внимательном рассмотрении вопроса, приходится признать правоту Академического справочника, ссылку из которого представил **Серж**. Действительно, в некоторых редких случаях глагол *контузить* может быть НСВ! Нашел один пример в Нацкорпусе :

> Алексей Иванов. Географ глобус пропил (2002) ***И его начинает*** месить и швырять, лупить волнами, душить пеной, ***контузить литыми
>
>   водяными зарядами***, хлестать струями...

По этому образцу нам уже легко составить два предложения, в которых форма глагола *контузит* является в двух видах.
НСВ : *В это время Петрова контузит (что делает?) разрывом фугаса и он падает (что делает?) на спину.* Оба глагола НСВ, наст. врем.
СВ : *В это время Петрова контузит (что сделает) разрывом фугаса и он упадет (что сделает?) на спину.* Оба глагола СВ, здесь будущее время в роли прошедшего (как это называется в лингвистике?)
Вывод. Прилагательное *контуженый*, которое обозначает постоянный признак (когда-то контуженный и неизлечившийся), пишем с одним Н. Причастие *контуженный* пишем с НН, для обозначения кратковременного и/или прошедшего признака (контуженный в бою), зависимые слова это должны подчеркивать.

Comment: Одного примера недостаточно, возможно,  это индивидуально-авторское значение слова  (что-то вроде окказионализма), которое применяется с целью усиления экспрессивности текста.  Начинает контузить - спорное выражение, если использовать прямое значение слова.

Comment: Согласно определению, КОНТУЗИЯ (лат. contusio — ушиб) — особый вид общего поражения организма, который возникает при ВНЕЗАПНОМ непрямом воздействии на всё тело, или на его обширные участки. Чаще всего возникает от взрывной воздушной волны. Характерным признаком контузии является потеря сознания (вплоть до комы). В лёгких случаях сознание утрачивается на несколько минут, в тяжёлых — на несколько дней и даже месяцев.

Comment: Единственный пример в Нацкорпусе - но какой яркий! Мой тоже очень хорош, согласитесь : *Внезапно разрывом фугаса контузит Петрова и он падает...* Получается уже два)

Comment: Ваш пример лучше, чем "начинает контузить", но тоже нехорош: Петрова разрывом снаряда могло просто легко ранить.  Да и исследования на тему дальнейшего его лечения  от контузии  очень сложны, мне кажется, что "контуженый" с одной Н следует писать только в переносном смысле (и разумеется, при отсутствии зависимых слов), например: "ты что, контуженый?".

Comment: Вера, пример который привел Грантум, вполне нормальный. Ведь может контузить подряд несколько раз. что и в нашем примере.

Answer (score 0):

Пишите с двумя ***н***.  Самое лучшее правило: " ведь глагол "контузить" совершенного вида, по правилу нужно писать две буквы ***н***. "

Comment: Да, по правилу нужно писать две буквы НН, но это формальное правило со многими исключениями. Настоящее правило: две буквы НН пишутся в причастиях и НН/Н - в отглагольных прилагательных. Вот и надо  подумать о том, что, может быть,  в некоторых случаях мы имеем дело с прилагательным, если обозначается явно качественный признак ("контуженый" в значении "ненормальный"). Примеры: В этот-то момент, словно контуженый водолаз, ты начинаешь медленное всплытие. Ты что, братик, контуженый? Как Вы считаете?